# Add to cart depending which checkbox is selected - Shopify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, liquid

I am trying to implement a functionality when either or multiple checkboxes are selected [ just one of 3, any 2 of 3 or all of them] and then "Continue" button is pressed certain product(s) (id) would be added to the cart.

HTML

```
<div class="start-container">
  <div class="start-row">
    <div class="start-column start-image">
      <img src='{{ 'start-1.jpg' | asset_url }}'>
      <div class="start-img-text">product1</div>
      <input class="start-input"type="checkbox" id="agree1" />
    </div>
    <div class="start-column start-image">
      <img src='{{ 'start-2.jpg' | asset_url }}'>
      <div class="start-img-text">product2</div>
      <input class="start-input"type="checkbox" id="agree2" />
    </div>
    <div class="start-column start-image">
      <img src='{{ 'start-3.jpg' | asset_url }}'>
      <div class="start-img-text">product3</div>
      <input class="start-input"type="checkbox" id="agree3" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="one-whole">
    <div class="start-btn">
      <button class="btn viking start-btn-style generic-button" id="add-all">CONTINUE</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add-selected').click(function(){
      addItemToCart(29445725192291, 1)
    });
  });

  function addItemToCart (variant_id, quantity) {
    data = {
      "quantity": quantity,
      "id": variant_id
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/cart/add',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("Item added to cart", data);
      }
    });
    window.location = '/cart';

  }
```

Comment: Please make your question answerable. You must provide dummy html for select item so we know your select data pattern.

Comment: BTW React makes these things a LOT easier!